# Godep restore doesn't use the code saved in _workspace

Tags: go, dependency-management

I started using `godep` a while ago but I think I'm failing to understand the principal, and I may be using it incorrectly entirely.

I thought `godep` maintains `_workspace` in order to have a local copy of the packages in case some revisions/projects are removed or become unavailable. But `godep restore` doesn't seem to use `_workspace` at all.

Also, calling `godep save` for the second time didn't update `_workspace`, only `Godeps.json`.

What am I missing?

---

UPDATE:

To explain my question I changed one of the revisions in my Godeps.json to an invalid revision "1" and ran `godep restore`. Here's the error I got:

```
$GOPATH/bin/godep restore
# cd /home/iliga/gopath/src/github.com/jinzhu/gorm; git pull --ff-only
From https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm 
a97a508..087b708  master     -> origin/master
You are not currently on a branch. Please specify which
branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for details.

git pull <remote> <branch>

# cd /home/iliga/gopath/src/github.com/jinzhu/gorm; git checkout 1
error: pathspec '1' did not match any file(s) known to git.
godep: restore: exit status 1
```

As explained above, I would expect there to be no error and for godep to simply copy the code from _workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"godep restore" does not use _workspace. It reads Godeps.json and check out your dependencies to GOPATH.

To use _workspace, you run go command prefixed with godep, like "godep go build", "godep go test".